SwiftUI Date keeps scrolling back to selected date
I am using SwiftUI Date Picker (iOS 16.2), however, after selecting a date, if try moving to select a different date, it keeps scrolling back to the date currently selected.
struct DatePickerExample: View {

  @State var expiry = Date.now

  let dateRange: ClosedRange<Date> = {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date()) ?? Date()
    let startComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents(
      [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: yesterday)
    let tenYearsFromNow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 10, to: Date()) ?? Date()
    let endComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents(
      [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: tenYearsFromNow)
    return calendar.date(from: startComponents)!...calendar.date(from: endComponents)!
  }()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      DatePicker(
        "Start Date",
        selection: $expiry,
        in: dateRange,
        displayedComponents: [.date]
      )
      .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
    }
  }
}


Sample issue can be seen here (credit to youngermann)

Cannot reproduce on iOS 17.4. Perhaps just a bug in the older iOS version.

@Sweeper No luck with increasing the iOS version
